# Set AllowOverride ALL on Apache 2.4 as default for domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos, cpanel

I recently updated from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 and noticed my sub-directories on some domains were no longer showing (visiting via http resulted in a blank page).  I am 50% confident this has something to do with the switch to default `AllowOverride` to 'none'.

Where do I set this to ALL so that the sub-directories will display again and is there a universal fix I can use to make it act as Apache 2.2 did or do I need to do it on a domain by domain or even directory by directory basis?

I am on a cPanel server (LAMP) with CentOs.

Comment: Why you put Cpanel tags if you don't run a Cpanel box?

Comment: I am sorry. My poor level of English led me to creee you spoke of a box without Cpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best way its use [WHM EA Custom Templates](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Custom+Templates)

- To create custom template files that affect how cPanel & WHM builds entries for all virtual hosts, perform the following steps:

  - Create a copy of one or more of the following files:

    - Apache 2.2 with SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_2/ssl_vhost.default
    - Apache 2.4 with SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ssl_vhost.default
    - Apache 2.2 without SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_2/vhost.default
    - Apache 2.4 without SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/vhost.default
  - Rename the copied file to one of the following filenames:

    - vhost.local — Use this filename if you copied the vhost.default file.
    - ssl_vhost.local — Use this filename if you copied the ssl_vhost.default file.
  - Edit the *.local files to make the desired changes to your virtual host configuration.

It's easy. After create your custom template

- /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
- service httpd restart

Comment: The files to copy do not exist.

Comment: This /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_XXX/ must by exist, if your WHM/Cpanel it's > 52.0 version. If not esiste you have a problem with your isntallation, or you don't know copy and paste lines.

Comment: Mine is above 52.0 but was updated to be so.  The directories do not exits however and the server/apache run fine.  This used to be on Apache 2.2 and EasyApache 3 and was upgraded ti EA4 and Apache 2.4